# change selectbox text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Basically, I have a jQuery modal that's getting content dynamically via an `onClick` then using the `data` attributes, I need to replace text inside a `<select></select>` to display an dynamic email address.

Here's the **HTML**

```
<select name="email" class="span4">
    <option id="holder" value="">Ticket Holder ('{ticket_holder}')</option>
    <option id="purchaser" value="">Ticket Purchaser ('{ticket_purchaser}')</option>
</select>
```

Here's the **jQuery** I attempted to use

```
$('select option:contains("{ticket_holder}")').text().replace("{ticket_holder}","Test");
```

Which failed to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var element = $('select option:contains("{ticket_holder}")');
var text = element.text();
element.text(text. replace("{ticket_holder}","Test"));
```

1. For assigning text to element you need to pass text into `.text()` function.
2. `.replace()` returns changed text, but doesn't change original.

Comment: You can also do `var text = element.text();` - no need to do the DOM selecting twice.

Answer (score 0):

`$.fn.text` also takes a [function as argument](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text), useful when you want to manipulate the contents:

```
$('select option:contains("{ticket_holder}")').text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/{ticket_holder}/, 'Test');
});
```